# Solving a first order differential equation by reducing it to a homogenous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Problem:

Solve the following differential equation.
$$ (3x-3y) \, dx + (2x+3y - 5) \,\, dy = 0 $$

Answer:

First we check to see if it is exact:
\begin{align*} 
M_y &= -3 \\
N_x &= 2 \\
\end{align*}
It is not exact and it is not homogenous but we can transform it to a
homogeneous differential equation. We setup the following system of
linear equations:
\begin{align*} 
3x - 3y &= 0 \\
2x + 3y - 5 &= 0 \\
x - y &= 0 \\
x &= y \\
2x + 3x - 5 &= 0 \\
x &= y = 1 \\
\end{align*}
Now we make the substitutions $u = x - 1$ and $v = y - 1$.
\begin{align*} 
du &= dx \\
dv &= dy \\
x &= u + 1 \\
y &= v + 1 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*} 
(3 (u+1) - 3(v+1) ) \, du + (2(u+1)+3(v+1) - 5) \,\, dv &= 0 \\
( 3u + 3 - 3v - 3 ) \, du + (2u + 2 + 3v + 3 - 5) \,\, dv &= 0 \\
( 3u - 3v ) \, du + (2u + 3v) \,\, dv &= 0 \\
( 3u - 3v ) \, du &= - (2u + 3v) \,\, dv \\
( 2u + 3v ) \, dv &= ( 3v - 3u) \, du \\
\dfrac{dv}{du} &= \dfrac{3v - 3u }{ 2u + 3v } \\
\dfrac{dv}{du} &= \dfrac{3 \left( \dfrac{v}{u} \right)  - 3 }
 { 2 + 3\left( \dfrac{v}{u}  \right)  } 
\end{align*}
Now let $v = uz$.
\begin{align*} 
\dfrac{ dv}{du} &= u \dfrac{ dz}{du} + z \\
z &= \dfrac{v}{u} \\
u \dfrac{dz}{du} + z &= \dfrac{3z-3}{2+3z} \\
u \dfrac{dz}{du} &= \dfrac{ 3z - 3 - z( 3z+2)}{3z+2} \\
u \dfrac{dz}{du} &= \dfrac{ 3z - 3 - 3z^2 - 2z}{3z+2} \\
u \dfrac{dz}{du} &= \dfrac{ -3z^2 + z - 3}{3z+2}  \\
\dfrac{du}{u} &= \dfrac{(3z+2)\,dz}{-3z^2 + z - 3} \\
\end{align*}
Using an online integral calculator, we find that:
$$ \int \dfrac{(3x+2)\,dz}{-3x^2 + x - 3} \, dz =
 -\left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) \ln\left(  3x^2 - x + 3 \right)
 - \sqrt{ \dfrac{5}{7} } \tan^{-1}\left( \dfrac{ 6x-1 }{ \sqrt{35}} \right) + C 
  $$
\begin{align*} 
\ln{|u|} &= -\left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) \ln\left(  3z^2 - z + 3 \right)
- \sqrt{ \dfrac{5}{7} } \tan^{-1}\left( \dfrac{ 6z-1 }{ \sqrt{35}} \right) + C \\
%
\ln{|u|} &= -\left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) 
  \ln\left(  3\left( \dfrac{v}{u}\right) ^2 - \dfrac{v}{u} + 3 \right)
 - \sqrt{ \dfrac{5}{7} } \tan^{-1}
  \left( \dfrac{ 6\left( \dfrac{v}{u}\right) -1 }{ \sqrt{35}} \right) + C \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ \ln{|x-1|} = -\left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) 
 \ln\left(  3\left( \dfrac{y-1}{x-1}\right) ^2 - \dfrac{y-1}{x-1} + 3 \right)
 - \sqrt{ \dfrac{5}{7} } \tan^{-1}
 \left( \dfrac{ 6\left( \dfrac{y-1}{x-1}\right) -1 }{ \sqrt{35}} \right) + C $$
Am I right?
ChatGPT says the right answer is:
$$ y = -e^{-x^2+xy} + C*e^{-x^2+xy}$$
However, I have reason to believe that it  is wrong,